# Sort by a truncated date in SOLR

Tags: sorting, solr

Is it possible to sort results from a SOLR query only on a truncated value of a date field (e.g. only on year-month excluding day and time)?
For example if I have

```xml
<doc>
  <field name="id">b</field>
  <field name="pubdate">2016-10-12T00:00:00Z</field>
  <field name="title">b</field>
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="id">c</field>
  <field name="pubdate">2016-10-13T00:00:00Z</field>
  <field name="title">c</field>
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="id">a</field>
  <field name="pubdate">2016-09-01T00:00:00Z</field>
  <field name="title">a</field>
</doc>
```

I would like to query using `sort=pubdate desc,title asc` and obtain:

```
b
c
a
```

I looked at [Function Queries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries) but I couldn't find any date truncate function.

Solr version is 5.5.0 and pubdate is a `TrieDateField`.

Comment: Not sure but it could work using date math expression, try : `sort=pubdate/MONTH desc,title asc`

Comment: Which field type do you use, `TrieDateField` or `DateRangeField`, and what version of Solr?

Comment: @ericLavault: it doesn't work using date math expression

Comment: @cheffe: I updated question adding info on solr version and field type.